# Prevent horizontal scrollbar for HTML table

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js

I'm using a Vuetify table with multiple columns like so

[Reproduction link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp9UstugzAQ/BXkc8Bt2l6iNErVS/sNIQcCTuMGP2Qb2gjx7901BGFHzY2dHWZ2Z73ryJvWWdswsiJrx4SuC8c2uUySdZsWWvtPX4iCy7HytSsO9cAcIXdiRTUDEDJB7UlJmx6Vec0JlxX7TbhMHh9ysvmAn5lJug4QxPt+Td0plKOBHvZDx7U7qOoSjzAZGvXzGXjGs1UTtVR1I+Q9du4gg7Iw4cZBJ3XcQUTvrK5RBOxxvWmKvkd0cMLG3BO3D0Rik2s73oG66AQ3mQURocz8kFhPh8ZieALw2/VpkAXhQivjgKezb6skvJwO6XBR37A5WSUeQQyeFtY5OTmn7YrSRurzV1YqQbfQo6aRjguWVkpsn7Jl9vxCK27dHM+YFekBcrPMgGNOFjNxx4+X/wzGNug+ZstBdoRQ8kaKgn7LTGoY3MAwc3fuiBvMHvVu5kfPPpc9ZFlzebZRjKX1Ee72SOkXZJAGst+D7P8AqBAeSQ==)

```
  <v-table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="index in 10">Header {{ index }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="rowIndex in 10">
        <td v-for="columnIndex in 10">
            <v-card>
            <v-card-title>Cell in row {{ rowIndex }} in column {{ columnIndex }}</v-card-title>
          </v-card>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </v-table>
```

For smaller screen sizes the horizontal scrollbar is perfectly fine. But there is a "print mode" where horizontal scrollbars make no sense ( data loss on PDF file ). So regardless of the actual table width I would like to prevent a horizontal scrollbar ( I'm aware that this might look very ugly ). I think this problem is not related to Vuetify, I think this also applies for plain HTML.

I tried to disable the horizontal scrollbar via `overflow-x: hidden;`

```css
div {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

td {
  padding: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <th>Header 6</th>
      <th>Header 7</th>
      <th>Header 8</th>
      <th>Header 9</th>
      <th>Header 10</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 1</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 2</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 3</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 4</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 5</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 6</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 7</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 8</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 9</td>
        <td>I'm a cell in row 1 in column 10</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

but unfortunately that didn't help. As you can see there is some content loss on the right side.

Do you have any ideas how to tell the content to shrink as much as possible?

Comment: Apply `overflow: hidden` to the `.v-table__wrapper` element that _contains_ the table ...?

Comment: yes you are right, but unfortunately some content gets lost on the right side https://jsfiddle.net/aL90d74q/2/

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply css rules differently for print screen

```
 @media print {
       body {
           overflow-x: visible
       }
 }
```

here `body` is the first parent element of table, you can apply it to the immediate parent of `table` and it will work in print mode.

`overflow-x: visible` property will print it adjusting the data in new line in print screen

Comment: I tried to reproduce it and yes, the scrollbar is gone but the content on right side is lost https://jsfiddle.net/aL90d74q/2/

Comment: updated the answer, check with this

Comment: you mean like so? https://jsfiddle.net/7kac65pz/1/ but then I have a scrollbar again =?

Comment: jsfiddle won't show actual print env, check in your project and let me know